# Java - Go back to beginning of program flow if condition failed

Tags: java, joptionpane

Just as I write this I can imagine how basic the question is but here I go ..

I have a Java client wherein I validate a 'date' input entered by user and if valid pass it along elsewhere. I am using JOptionPane to show input dialog box.

Basically when an invalid date format is entered by the user my program quits and the user has to restart the program again. Instead of that I wanted the pop-up inputdialog box to be shown after 'Invalid Date Entered" message is displayed. What would be the best way to pass control to that line of code again ?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Client {

  static SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream IP = null;
    //  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    try {

      IP = new FileInputStream("Client.properties");
      prop.load(IP);
      String host = prop.getProperty("ServerIP");
      String port = prop.getProperty("Port");
      int port1 = Integer.parseInt(port);

      Socket s = new Socket(host, port1);
      String reportDate = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Date:");
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);

      /**
       * User Input Validation
       */
      if (reportDate.matches("^((19|20)\\d\\d)-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$")) {

        out.println(reportDate);
        s.close();

        System.exit(0);
      } //if
      else {
        String Error = "INCORRECT date format entered!";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Error);
      } //else
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      if (IP != null) {
        try {
          IP.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not directly related, but use try-with-resources to create your inputstream and socket. It removes the `finally` boilerplate (and the cases where you're not closing the socket currently).

Comment: Create a loop where the exit condition is a Date formatted correctly.

Comment: Do you know how to use do-while loops? I'm not the best to explain it, but they would most definitely solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

As you use `System.exit(0)` in the success case, just wrap your code in an endless loop with `while (true) { }`.

Comment: ...although `return` (or `break`, once you've got a loop) might be better than `System.exit(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this (pseudocode):

```
String reportDate = "badDate";
while (!reportDate.matches("^((19|20)\\d\\d)-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$"))
{
//do all the things that are currently in your if statement
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not directly related to the response you are looking for. In fact the direct answer to your question is use a loop and it will work the way you are expecting.

However, if you want to do this for selecting date you should consider using **Java SwingX**.

[SwingX](http://swinglabs.org/downloads.jsp) library has a lot of good components including excellent date picker

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you to take a valid `Date`:

```
Date reportDate;
do { 
    try {
        String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Date:");
        reportDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(str);
        break;// loop break when got a valid date e.g. 2016-09-16
    } catch (Exception mistake) {
        System.err.println("Invalid input: " + mistake);
    }
} while (true);
```